# SWT FileDialog custom settings

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is there a way to add custom options to a SWT FileDialog like the image format dropdown in paint.net? The only alternative I can think of is creating a dialog, like the one in eclipse for creating a class, where there is a text field for the path and a button to open a FileDialog and a separate dropdown menu to select the file type, for example.

[image: paint.net Export Menu]

Comment: `"like the image format dropdown in paint.net?"`. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this. When I utilize a SWT FileDialog (through code in my IDE) I get the identical OPEN file dialog as what Paint.net displays. Do you mean to modify the **File Type** drop down box to basically display whatever you want for file types and the dialog will only display those files for the type selected? This can easily be done using the **FileDialog.setFilterNames()** and **FileDialog.setFilterExtensions()** methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to add more variables the user can set when exporting. But your method might be useful somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to customize the standard SWT `FileDialog`.

This dialog looks very different on different platforms (macOS, Linux, Windows) because it uses the native file dialog. This would make it very difficult to provide any meaningful customization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using the alternative described in my question, which ended up looking pretty good.